# Change color of the text area extend arrow

Tags: css, textarea

In the text area right bottom corner there is a small arrow to extend it in Chrome. Is there a way to change its color with CSS?

```
<textarea rows="3" id="textarea" placeholder="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rW5d2/1/ should work

Answer (score 1):

Working Solution: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/n5mpT/)

You can do it for webkit using `::-webkit-resizer` selector

```
::-webkit-resizer {
    background: url(http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.png);    
    background-size:100%;    
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: looks like it works only in webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Opera, Maxthon), others won't work (the `-moz-` also does not work for FireFox), here is the similar demo using dynamic background instead of image http://jsfiddle.net/2AFGK/9/

Comment: @KingKing u can implement anything because it supports background property.

Comment: have you tried it **cross-browser**? I don't mean the background, **I mean the `::-webkit-resizer`**

Answer (score 0):

In webkit browsers it can be styled with `::-webkit-resizer`.